# Unexpected token '<' at <html> tag

Tags: node.js, webpack, handlebars.js

this is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
//const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const htmlInlineCssPlugin = require("html-inline-css-webpack-plugin").default;
const htmlInlineSourcePlugin = require("html-webpack-inline-source-plugin");
var serverConfig = {
    entry: "./src/server.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname,'/bundle'),
        filename: "server_bundle.js"
    },
    "target": "node",
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node-modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
           { 
            test: /\.hbs$/,
            use: {
                loader: "handlebars-loader"
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    plugins: [
          new htmlWebpackPlugin({
              inlineSource: '.(js|css)$' 
          }),
          new htmlInlineSourcePlugin(),
    ]
}
module.exports = serverConfig;
```

this is my server.js

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
//let Email = require("email-templates");
let path = require('path');
app.get("/getHandleBar",function(req,res){
    var a = require( path.join(__dirname,"helpers","abc.hbs"));
    res.send(a());
    console.log(a());
})
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("app is listening on port 3000");
})
```

**when i am accessing 
http://localhost:3000/getHandleBar getting the following error**..Actually i am trying to get compiled email templates dynamically using webpack.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at D:\nodeapp\src\server.js:39:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\nodeapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\nodeapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
```

my handlebar is

```
<html>
    <head>
        {{!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/helpers/abc.css"></link> --}}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>This is a</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also this is my folder structure : please refer the screenshot 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVW5n.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Opening and closing tag of your comment in the bind variable is missing '<' '>'.

```
    {{!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/helpers/abc.css"></link> --}}

    {{<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/helpers/abc.css"></link> -->}}
```

Comment: after removing this line also getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `res.sendFile()` instead of `res.send()`.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files

```js
app.get("/getHandleBar",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"helpers","abc.hbs"));
})
```